# Cross-platform file cache in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

In a Flutter app I would like to implement a cache for resources (images, videos,...) that are hosted online.

I would expect it to work on native platforms (Android/iOS) (e.g using the filesystem) and also on the web (e.g using IndexedDB).

[Flutter Cache Manager](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_manager) doesn't work on the web. And [dart:indexed_db](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-indexed_db/dart-indexed_db-library.html) doesn't work on Android/iOS.

Is there any plugin that would be suitable for that purpose ?

Comment: Would these serve your purpose? [simple_cache](https://pub.dev/packages/simple_cache) or [flutter_cached](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cached)

Comment: @Benjamin Does flutter_cached actually handle cache persistence ? It seems that you actually need to implement it yourself.

Comment: Implementing it wouldn't hurt, especially with a plugin like localstorage. I think it's the best you're going to get if you want multiplatform compatibility.

Comment: @Benjamin `localstorage` seems to fit my need. Do you know how it stores data on Android ?

Comment: Looking at the source, it seems to do it just by creating a file with `dart:io`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally implemented this cache using [async_resource](https://pub.dev/packages/async_resource) library, using `ServiceWorkerResource` on the Web and `HttpNetworkResource` + `FileResource` on native platforms.

Comment: hi, could you share your implementation?